# "Gosh" and "bon sang"

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais

> Gosh, I didn't expect to see you here!

Gosh is used (an exclamation in this context) to express (informally) surprise or strength of feeling. [Gosh can be also used as a euphemism for ‘God’. E.g. "a gosh-awful team".]

Can "bon sang" or "Palsambleu" convey the meaning as in the following sentence?

> Bon sang/Palsambleu, je m'attendais pas à te voir ici !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Bon sang*** is quite outdated and expresses some upsetting.

***Palsambleu*** is extremely outdated and only used jocularly nowadays.

Referring to God might be done with ***Mon Dieu !*** but it expresses a fear and is becoming quite rare too.

Surprise can be expressed with:

> ***[Ça alors](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A7a_alors)**, je m'attendais pas à te voir ici !*

Also:

> ***Ah ben ça alors**,...*

Comment: Merci pour la réponse rapide ! Donc, quelles exclamations pourraient exprimer la surprise dans ce contexte ? Mince, par exemple ?

Comment: *Mince* is outdated too.

Comment: J'entendais « (ben) dis donc » utilisé dans les contexts similaires (pour exprimer de la  surprise), et aussi « purée », mais je pense que ça veut dire quelque chose plus...dommage? Et dans votre exemple, il me semble que c'est un situation plutôt ravi, comme un heureux hasard. Mais je ne suis pas un natif, donc peut-être je me trompe.

Comment: @DerekAllums *Ben dis donc* ajoute souvent une nuance de désapprobation. *Purée* peut en effet, parmi d'autres sentiments, exprimer la surprise comme de nombreuses autres expressions plus ou moins régionales telles que *Putain*, *Merde*, *Oh con*, *Ouah fatche de con* (Marseille), *Boudiou* (Provence), *Bouducon* (Toulouse)...

Comment: Merci @jlliagre !

Comment: Diantre, fichtre, quelle vocable châtié sur ce Q&A (et en plus, ça rime).

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/91/23719

Comment: @jlliagre justement, je m'attendais à des traductions plus vulgaire, et surement moins désuètes que Palsambleu :)